# spring rabbitmq unit test result is null

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am writing Spring rabbitmq unit test.

However, the result is always null.

`2020-02-05 11:36:53,113 ERROR o.s.a.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate - No correlation header in reply`

These messages are exposed.

What exactly does no correlation header in reply mean?

If check the log of the business logic, the result is returned correctly.

I don't know which one is the problem.

```
Object result = rabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(exchange, routingKey, requestMap);
// always result is null
```

Comment: You need to show the actual test as well as the code that is responding to the test - the correlation id must be echoed back by the server so the client knows which request a reply is for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which library for unit tests you are using, but the common libraries as Mockito or EasyMock are not capable to mock RabbitMQ, then the result object is always null.

See this link:
[I need to mock a RabbitMQ in my unit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37113377/i-need-to-mock-a-rabbitmq-in-my-unit-test/51381721)

Comment: No mocking is done, and the result of convertSendAndReceive method is null.